# How to detect DOM element position to use different CSS style via CSS selection

Tags: css

currently I have to different DOM struct like following:

the struct after browser translate is

```
No.1
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-control">zzz</span>
  <select class="form-control form-control single loading"></select>
  <div class="selectize-control"> 
    <div class="selectize-input items has-options full has-items"></div>
    <div class="selectize-dropdown form-control single"></div>
   </div>
</div>

No.2
<div class="input-group">
  <select class="form-control form-control single loading"></select>
  <div class="selectize-control"> 
    <div class="selectize-input items has-options full has-items"></div>
    <div class="selectize-dropdown form-control single"></div>
  </div>
  <span class="input-control">zzz</span>
</div>
```

I would like to set No.1 .selectize-input a new style
border-bottom-left-radius:0px;
border-top-left-radius:0px;

and set No.2 .selectize-input a new style
border-bottom-right-radius:0px;
border-top-right-radius:0px;

How can I make it?

Thanks

Comment: can you please elaborate it?

Comment: When <span> tag is in front of <select> tag, I would like to use A style. And when <span> tag is be hide the <select> tag then use B style. is it clear? ^^

Comment: @Kun-yaoWang **behind** not **be hide**, although it should be **after** in this case.

Comment: @Kun-yaoWang are those structures strict? or there may be some slight difference in future change?

Comment: @KingKing thanks for your correction, Yes, "after" ^^

Comment: @KingKing the only change is <span> tag~ title sometimes before select sometimes after select~

Comment: now I use  .input-group div:nth-child(1) then I can catch it, but i would like to div tag as being cached as level..

Comment: There is a Copy-Paste error - I think you are missing a `</selected>` tag :)

Comment: @Kun-yaoWang if you always have a div `.input-group` which contains the select and the span, this should work http://jsfiddle.net/xucqF/3/

Comment: .input-group div:nth-child(1) this way is able to catch tag is in font of select and then i try this .input-group:nth-child(2):first-child to catch another, but it does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.input-group > .input-group-addon ~ div.selectize-control > .selectize-input {
            ..
}



.input-group > div.selectize-control > .selectize-input {
            ..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since span and selectized are siblings, you can use the sibling selector. And set a base style for the oposite occurence, that will be overwritten if needed:

```
.input-group  span {
    background-color:red;
}
.input-group .selectized ~ span {
    background-color:green;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xucqF/6/)

Comment: I would like to catch .selectize-input and set it a new style~~ 
I had updated the question content, thanks for your time